# Spring Stripes framework problem

Tags: java, spring, stripes

I am new to stripes and am attempting to integrate spring into stripes
In the following code :

```
public class ContactFormActionBeanTest {
private static MockServletContext mockServletContext;
private static MockHttpSession mockSession;

@BeforeClass
public static void setup() throws Exception {
    mockServletContext = new MockServletContext("webmail");

    Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String,String>();
    params.put("ActionResolver.Packages", "stripesbook.action");

    params.put("Extension.Packages", "stripesbook.ext,"
        + "net.sourceforge.stripes.integration.spring");

    mockServletContext.addFilter(StripesFilter.class,
        "StripesFilter", params);

    mockServletContext.setServlet(DispatcherServlet.class,
        "DispatcherServlet", null);

    mockSession = new MockHttpSession(mockServletContext);


    mockServletContext.addInitParameter("contextConfigLocation",
        "/WEB-INF/applicationContext-test.xml");

    ContextLoaderListener springContextLoader =
        new ContextLoaderListener();
    springContextLoader.contextInitialized(
        new ServletContextEvent(mockServletContext));


    // Load mock user
    MockRoundtrip trip = new MockRoundtrip(mockServletContext,
        MockDataLoaderActionBean.class, mockSession);
    trip.execute();

    // Login mock user
    trip = new MockRoundtrip(mockServletContext,
        LoginActionBean.class, mockSession);
    trip.setParameter("username", "freddy");
    trip.setParameter("password", "nadia");
    trip.execute("login");
}
```

I get null in `springContextLoader`

```
    ContextLoaderListener springContextLoader = new ContextLoaderListener();
```

and test fails. Am I missing something?

I am using eclipse with maven.

Also when I try to deploy it for tomcat 6.0 I get following warnings:

> WARN  net.sourceforge.stripes.util.ResolverUtil  - Could not examine class 'stripesbook/ext/ContactFormatter.class' due to a java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError with message: Bad version number in .class file (unable to load class stripesbook.ext.ContactFormatter)

I have checked to be sure that I am compiling with Java 5(set JDK compiler to 1.5) instead of 1.6 (Java 6); but didn't work out for me and still have problems running spring-stripes integrated project.

---

I also have this code which fails in Test:

```
    @Test
    public void testEmailRequired() throws Exception {
        MockRoundtrip trip = new MockRoundtrip(mockServletContext,
                ContactFormActionBean.class, mockSession);

        trip.execute("save");

        ContactFormActionBean bean =
            trip.getActionBean(ContactFormActionBean.class);

        assertEquals(1,
                bean.getContext().getValidationErrors().size());

        assertEquals(MockRoundtrip.DEFAULT_SOURCE_PAGE,
                trip.getDestination());
    }
The error is in this line:
ContactFormActionBean bean =
            trip.getActionBean(ContactFormActionBean.class);
```

Error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at stripesbook.test.stripesmock.ContactFormActionBeanTest.testEmailRequired(ContactFormActionBeanTest.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at stripesbook.test.stripesmock.ContactFormActionBeanTest.testEmailRequired(ContactFormActionBeanTest.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner
```

Comment: What does "I get null in springContextLoader" mean? You get an exception?  If so, show us the exception.  Also, what version of Java are you running tomcat with?  And how are you compiling the code?

Comment: I ran maven install to get war file in java 5 .springContextLoader is null. I guess It's shouldn't be null.

Comment: I’m confused, this is a JUnit test, how can it be deployed to Tomcat? Anyway, if you install the latest Java 6 JVM then Tomcat will be able to execute all Java code compiled for older JVM versions. An other area for trouble is mixing 64/32 bit JVM’s with 64/32 bit Tomcat.

Comment: You're Tomcat error seems to be the result of running Tomcat in a Java 5 JVM but that you use (pre-compiled?) 'stripesbook/ext/ContactFormatter' class that is compiled for Java 6 JVM.

Comment: Sorry for my confusing question.After a while I don't know what happened but jUnit passed my testEmailRequired function successfully.I have new problem which I will post it in new POST.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682543/problem-using-mockroundtrip-class