# Problem using MockRoundtrip class

Tags: spring, junit, stripes

I have following code:

```
@Test
 public void testSaveValid() throws Exception {
  MockRoundtrip trip = new MockRoundtrip(mockServletContext,
    ContactFormActionBean.class, mockSession);

  trip.setParameter("contact.email", "test@test.com");
  trip.setParameter("contact.phoneNumber", "654-456-4567");
  trip.execute("save");

  ContactFormActionBean bean =
   trip.getActionBean(ContactFormActionBean.class);

  assertEquals(0,
    bean.getContext().getValidationErrors().size());

  PhoneNumber pn = bean.getContact().getPhoneNumber();
  assertEquals("654", pn.getAreaCode());
  assertEquals("456", pn.getPrefix());
  assertEquals("4567", pn.getSuffix());

  assertTrue(
    trip.getDestination().startsWith("/ContactList.action"));
 }
```

I encounter this error:

```
net.sourceforge.stripes.exception.StripesServletException: Unhandled exception in exception handler.
 at net.sourceforge.stripes.exception.DefaultExceptionHandler.handle(DefaultExceptionHandler.java:158)
 at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.StripesFilter.doFilter(StripesFilter.java:249)
 at net.sourceforge.stripes.mock.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:63)
 at net.sourceforge.stripes.mock.MockServletContext.acceptRequest(MockServletContext.java:255)
 at net.sourceforge.stripes.mock.MockRoundtrip.execute(MockRoundtrip.java:195)
 at net.sourceforge.stripes.mock.MockRoundtrip.execute(MockRoundtrip.java:207)
 at stripesbook.test.stripesmock.ContactFormActionBeanTest.testSaveValid(ContactFormActionBeanTest.java:96)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
 at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
 at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
 at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
 at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

If I delete

```
trip.setParameter("contact.email", "test@test.com");
trip.setParameter("contact.phoneNumber", "654-456-4567");
```

I won't get any errors but will get following message from jUnit:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<0> but was:<1>
```

which seems logical.
This is my ContactFormActionBean class

```
public class ContactFormActionBean extends ContactBaseActionBean {
private static final String FORM="/WEB-INF/jsp/contact_form.jsp";

@DefaultHandler
public Resolution form() {
    return new ForwardResolution(FORM);
}
public Resolution save() {
    Contact contact = getContact();
    contact.setUser(getUser());
    contactDao.save(contact);
    contactDao.commit();
    getContext().getMessages().add(
        getLocalizableMessage("contactSaved", contact)
    );
    return new RedirectResolution(ContactListActionBean.class);
}
@ValidationMethod(on="save")
public void validateEmailUnique(ValidationErrors errors) {
    String email = getContact().getEmail();
    Contact other = contactDao.findByEmail(email, getUser());
    if (other != null && !other.equals(getContact())) {
        errors.add("contact.email", new LocalizableError(
          getClass().getName()+".contactEmailAlreadyUsed", other));
    }
    }
}
```

Why this error happens?

[ADDED]

This is my Setup() function where I configure mockServletContext before running any test functions:

```
... 
    private static MockServletContext mockServletContext;
    private static MockHttpSession mockSession;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setup() throws Exception {
        mockServletContext = new MockServletContext("webmail");

        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String,String>();
        params.put("ActionResolver.Packages", "stripesbook.action");

        params.put("Extension.Packages", "stripesbook.ext,"
                + "net.sourceforge.stripes.integration.spring");

        mockServletContext.addFilter(StripesFilter.class,
                "StripesFilter", params);

        mockServletContext.setServlet(DispatcherServlet.class,
                "DispatcherServlet", null);

        mockSession = new MockHttpSession(mockServletContext);


        mockServletContext.addInitParameter("contextConfigLocation",
        "/WEB-INF/applicationContext-test.xml");

        ContextLoaderListener springContextLoader =
            new ContextLoaderListener();
        springContextLoader.contextInitialized(
                new ServletContextEvent(mockServletContext));
        // Load mock user
        MockRoundtrip trip = new MockRoundtrip(mockServletContext,
                MockDataLoaderActionBean.class, mockSession);
        trip.execute();

        // Login mock user
        trip = new MockRoundtrip(mockServletContext,
                LoginActionBean.class, mockSession);
        trip.setParameter("username", "freddy");
        trip.setParameter("password", "nadia");
        trip.execute("login");
    }
...
```

I think there could be some config problems cause when I remove

```
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/webapp" />
```

from class path I get different error :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-test.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-test.xml]
```

Comment: StripesServletException should be wrapping an exception (the one that we're really interested in).  Can you post the whole error message?

Comment: I have posted the full stack error. I don't what else is needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a Stripes configuration problem.

Did you configure the `mockServletContext` correctly?

Comment: Thanks for your post,I have edited my question and added stuff related to configuration.It would be great if you mind having a look.

Comment: **(1)** First make sure your app. Runs in your servlet container (for example Tomcat). **(2)** Use this configuration as you’re JUnit configuration: use an identical class path, same Spring applicationContext.xml and make sure you’re MockServletContext config has the same configuration options as the web.xml you use in your servlet container. **(3)** Done!

Answer (score 1):

U tried with Spring ?

I have done it with :

Object test=  springContextListener.getContextLoader().getCurrentWebApplicationContext().getBean("MyActionBean");

annoted your class with : @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)

Comment: No I am using Stripes and also injected spring beans.THis is Fredric's book,Pragmatic programmers. P272.

Answer (score 0):

**concerning org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException**: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-test.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-test.xml]

add :

**@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class** to your test Class

and add Spring-test Jar to your project.

Comment: I did that but when it runs any code that has  return new RedirectResolution ,it will throw exception ERROR:  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier.testAborted(Lorg/junit/runner/Description;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V

Comment: You don't need to add the @RunWith annotation, all Spring initialization is done by the Stripes Mock environment!

Answer (score 0):

recheck the line  : **filterParams.put("ActionResolver.Packages", "yourapplicationpackagesPath.action");**